# how to use dcast on a dataframe that has only 1 row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape2

Hi I have a dataframe like this

```
Start <- c("A")
End <- c("C")
Days <- c("Day1")

df2 <- data.frame(Start,End,Days)
```

I am trying to use dcast

```
df2 <- dcast(df2,Days ~ End,value.var="Days")
```

but it returns is

```
  Days    C
1 Day1 Day1
```

My desired output is the count

```
  Days    C
1 Day1    1
```

What am I missing here? Kindly provide some inputs on this. Is there a better way to do this using dplyr?

Comment: Where is the `1` supposed to come from? The row number?

Comment: It's the count of how many C's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a sequence column of 1 and then use `dcast`

```
 dcast(transform(df2, i1=1), Days~End, value.var='i1')
#  Days C
#1 Day1 1
```

Or another option is using the `fun.aggregate`

```
dcast(df2, Days~End, length)
#  Days C
#1 Day1 1
```

---

As the OP mentioned about `dplyr`, it involves using the first method as it doesn't have the `fun.aggregate`

```
 library(dplyr)
 df2 %>%
    mutate(C=1) %>%
    select(Days:C)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you are on the right track. What you need when you cast your data frame is to have a function that is applied to the aggregation during the casting.

In this case , you want something that counts the occurence of each group to do so you use the function length

`dcast(df2,Days ~ End, length ) # or dcast(df, Days ~ End, table)`

Comment: You were right. length is what I was missing there. Thanks @biobirdman